# Spring choose bean implementation at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm using Spring Beans with annotations and I need to choose different implementation at runtime.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   public void test(){...}
}
```

For example for windows's platform I need `MyServiceWin extending MyService`, for linux platform I need `MyServiceLnx extending MyService`.

For now I know only one horrible solution:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private MyService impl;

   @PostInit
   public void init(){
        if(windows) impl=new MyServiceWin();
        else impl=new MyServiceLnx();
   }

   public void test(){
        impl.test();
   }
}
```

Please consider that I'm using annotation only and not XML config.

Comment: What's wrong with `@Qualifier` if all your class names are different?

Comment: Mmh, if I'm not wrong, Qualifier is not evalutated runtime.

Comment: True that. You probably should look at a factory pattern. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### 1. Implement a custom [`Condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html)

```
public class LinuxCondition implements Condition {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux");  }
}
```

Same for `Windows`.

#### 2. Use [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) in your `Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean
   @Conditional(LinuxCondition.class)
   public MyService getMyLinuxService() {
      return new LinuxService();
   }

   @Bean
   @Conditional(WindowsCondition.class)
   public MyService getMyWindowsService() {
      return new WindowsService();
   }
}
```

#### 3. Use `@Autowired` as usual

```
@Service
public class SomeOtherServiceUsingMyService {

    @Autowired    
    private MyService impl;

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I tried the @ Profile solution and that works for me. I think this can be also a good solution, but with @ Profile I don't need a configurator.

Comment: @grep You're right. I fixed the method names. Note that you're autowiring based on type `MyService` using `Conditional` so the method names for the bean definition do not take precedence and single configuration with different method names should work.

Comment: In this case what happens to your autowiring if both conditions are met?

Comment: What if I want to use some variable inside `matches`?

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't need "new" so you don't have to specify all the constructor parameters but instead use dependency injection, e.g. via `Lombok`.

Answer (score 31):

Let's create beautiful config.

Imagine that we have **Animal** interface and we have **Dog** and **Cat** implementation. We want  to write write:

```
@Autowired
Animal animal;
```

but which implementation should we return?

[image]

So what is solution?  There are many ways to solve problem. I will write how to use   **@Qualifier** and Custom Conditions together.

So First off all let's create our custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface AnimalType {
    String value() default "";
}
```

and config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class AnimalFactoryConfig {

    @Bean(name = "AnimalBean")
    @AnimalType("Dog")
    @Conditional(AnimalCondition.class)
    public Animal getDog() {
        return new Dog();
    }

    @Bean(name = "AnimalBean")
    @AnimalType("Cat")
    @Conditional(AnimalCondition.class)
    public Animal getCat() {
        return new Cat();
    }

}
```

**Note** our bean name is **AnimalBean**. **why do we need this bean?** because when we inject Animal interface we will write just **@Qualifier("AnimalBean")**

Also we crated **custom annotation** to pass the value to our **custom Condition**.

Now our conditions look like this (imagine that "Dog" name comes from config file or JVM parameter or...)

```
   public class AnimalCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        if (annotatedTypeMetadata.isAnnotated(AnimalType.class.getCanonicalName())){
           return annotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnimalType.class.getCanonicalName())
                   .entrySet().stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getValue().equals("Dog"));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and finally injection:

```
@Qualifier("AnimalBean")
@Autowired
Animal animal;
```

Comment: I don't think Qualifier should be mixed with Autowired

Comment: Why dont you think they should be mixed?

Answer (score 30):

You can move the bean injection into the configuration, as:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService getMyService() {
        if(windows) return new MyServiceWin();
        else return new MyServiceLnx();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use profiles `windows` and `linux`, then annotate your service implementations with the `@Profile` annotation, like `@Profile("linux")` or `@Profile("windows")`, and provide one of this profiles for your application.

Comment: I could set the Spring profile via web.xml but is it possibile to change it in a ContextListerner with a bit of code? With this I can change the profile runtime as requested.

Comment: Since Spring 4(?) you have the `@Conditional` annotation at your disposal. `@Profile` will work 100%, but the [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) should be better suited.

Comment: @demaniak if I'm reading the docs for Conditional correctly, it sounds like it's evaluated at startup, not runtime?

Comment: @CharlesWood - yes, you are correct. But, with the addion of "@RefreshScope", and the Actuator starter, it is possible to get a reload at runtime. You would of course have to carefully consider the impact of that on a running system!

Comment: Why would this still be called AppConfig? Technically isn't this like a factory pattern?

Answer (score 18):

Autowire all your implementations into a factory with `@Qualifier` annotations, then return the service class you need from the factory.

```
public class MyService {
    private void doStuff();
}
```

My Windows Service:

```
@Service("myWindowsService")
public class MyWindowsService implements MyService {

    @Override
    private void doStuff() {
        //Windows specific stuff happens here.
    }
}
```

My Mac Service:

```
@Service("myMacService")
public class MyMacService implements MyService {

    @Override
    private void doStuff() {
        //Mac specific stuff happens here
    }
}
```

My factory:

```
@Component
public class MyFactory {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myWindowsService")
    private MyService windowsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myMacService")
    private MyService macService;

    public MyService getService(String serviceNeeded){
        //This logic is ugly
        if(serviceNeeded == "Windows"){
            return windowsService;
        } else {
            return macService;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get really tricky you can use an enum to store your implementation class types, and then use the enum value to choose which implementation you want to return.

```
public enum ServiceStore {
    MAC("myMacService", MyMacService.class),
    WINDOWS("myWindowsService", MyWindowsService.class);

    private String serviceName;
    private Class<?> clazz;

    private static final Map<Class<?>, ServiceStore> mapOfClassTypes = new HashMap<Class<?>, ServiceStore>();

    static {
        //This little bit of black magic, basically sets up your 
        //static map and allows you to get an enum value based on a classtype
        ServiceStore[] namesArray = ServiceStore.values();
        for(ServiceStore name : namesArray){
            mapOfClassTypes.put(name.getClassType, name);
        }
    }

    private ServiceStore(String serviceName, Class<?> clazz){
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String getServiceBeanName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public static <T> ServiceStore getOrdinalFromValue(Class<?> clazz) {
        return mapOfClassTypes.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

Then your factory can tap into the Application context and pull instances into it's own map. When you add a new service class, just add another entry to the enum, and that's all you have to do.

```
 public class ServiceFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

     private final Map<String, MyService> myServices = new Hashmap<String, MyService>();

     public MyService getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
         return myServices.get(ServiceStore.getOrdinalFromValue(clazz).getServiceName());
     }

      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
          myServices.putAll(applicationContext.getBeansofType(MyService.class));
      }
 }
```

Now you can just pass the class type you want into the factory, and it will provide you back the instance you need. Very helpful especially if you want to the make the services generic.

Comment: Good application of Delegate pattern - in theory. In practice, it introduces some overhead on extending MyService - each method added should also be implemented by MyFactory (which is BTW not Factory but Proxy). That's OK while MyService only have a method or two, but becomes tedious as MyService grows.

Answer (score 9):

Simply make the `@Service` annotated classes conditional:
**That's all.** No need for other explicit `@Bean` methods.

```
public enum Implementation {
    FOO, BAR
}

@Configuration
public class FooCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Implementation implementation = Implementation.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("implementation"));
        return Implementation.FOO == implementation;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class BarCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Implementation implementation = Implementation.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("implementation"));
        return Implementation.BAR == implementation;
    }
}
```

Here happens the magic.
The condition is right where it belongs: At the implementating classes.

```
@Conditional(FooCondition.class)
@Service
class MyServiceFooImpl implements MyService {
    // ...
}

@Conditional(BarCondition.class)
@Service
class MyServiceBarImpl implements MyService {
    // ...
}
```

You can then use `Dependency Injection` as usual, e.g. via `Lombok`'s `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or `@Autowired`.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyApp {
    private final MyService myService;
    // ...
}
```

Put this in your application.yml:

```
implementation: FOO
```

**Only the implementations annotated with the** `FooCondition` **will be instantiated. No phantom instantiations.**

Comment: Nice  & clear 
How would one write integration tests for these?
If I had an integration test for Foo, how to set implementation property = foo. Similarly for the case when implementation property = bar.

Comment: Probably the same as you would with other tests that rely on application properties

Answer (score 9):

Just adding my 2 cents to this question. Note that one doesn't have to implement so many java classes as the other answers are showing. One can simply use the [@ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html). Example:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value="property.my.service", 
  havingValue = "foo", 
  matchIfMissing = true)
class MyServiceFooImpl implements MyService {
    // ...
}

@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value="property.my.service", 
  havingValue = "bar")
class MyServiceBarImpl implements MyService {
    // ...
}
```

Put this in your application.yml:

```
property.my.service: foo
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution that leverages Spring. 
Notice that `value` is not an array of string and that the property can be overwritten by an env variable called PROPERTY_MY_SERVICE.

Comment: This approach looks cleanest to me as well and is documented in a Spring blog: [4 Solutions for Selective Injection](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-04/spring-selective-injection/).

Answer (score 2):

MyService.java:

```
public interface MyService {
  String message();
}
```

MyServiceConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfig {

  @Value("${service-type}")
  MyServiceTypes myServiceType;

  @Bean
  public MyService getMyService() {
    if (myServiceType == MyServiceTypes.One) {
      return new MyServiceImp1();
    } else {
      return new MyServiceImp2();
    }
  }
}
```

application.properties:

```
service-type=one
```

MyServiceTypes.java

```
public enum MyServiceTypes {
  One,
  Two
}
```

Use in any Bean/Component/Service/etc. like:

```
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    ...
    String message = myService.message()
```

Comment: The `getMyService()` config method needs `@Primary` to prevent having too many implementations to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with AOP (AspectJ)

```
@AutowiredCustom
public SpeedLimitService speedLimitService;
```

Aspect:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import performance.context.CountryHolder;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 */
@Aspect
@Component
public aspect AutowiredCustomFieldAspect implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    pointcut annotatedField(): get(@performance.annotation.AutowiredCustom * *);

    before(Object object): annotatedField() && target(object) {
        try {
            String fieldName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
            Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            String className = field.getType().getSimpleName() + CountryHolder.getCountry().name();

            Object bean = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean(className);

            field.set(object, bean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Beans:

```
@Service("SpeedLimitServiceCH")
public class SpeedLimitServiceCH implements SpeedLimitService {

    @Override
    public int getHighwaySpeedLimit() {
        return 120;
    }
}

@Service("SpeedLimitServiceDE")
public class SpeedLimitServiceDE implements SpeedLimitService {

    @Override
    public int getHighwaySpeedLimit() {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

pom.xml configuration

```
...
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
    
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**Reference:**
https://viktorreinok.medium.com/dependency-injection-pattern-for-cleaner-business-logic-in-your-java-spring-application-f4ace0a3cba7