# Spring - dependency injection through user input?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I started to learn Spring recently and I want to know if it's possible to "select" a component based on user input.

Example: I have a user interface that lets you select your gender: Male or Female. Is it possible to to "inject" the option selected by the user?

Sorry if I did not use the correct terminology... I'm still new to this.

Comment: yes, you can use Factory Pattern or implement Custom Condition. Please refer to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350865/spring-choose-bean-implementation-at-runtime if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if I get it... but I'll do my best :)